# PHP $SESSION deosn't store in Live Server after refresh page or header to another pages

Tags: php, session, server

I try to work on SESSION in Live Server (NameCheap), but session is automatically destroy when I refresh the page. mean that session is not storing in the Live Server.

After I clicked Login Button, Session is stored, but when I refresh the page or header to another page, session is automatic destroy.

// Start Session

```
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

// If Isset Button

```
if(isset($_POST["btnStudent"])){
```

// Get Value From Input

```
$studentUsername    = input($_POST["studentUsername"]);
$studentPassword    = input($_POST["studentPassword"]);
```

// Query User in Database

```
$QUERYSTUDENT       = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `USERNAME` FROM `".DBPREFIX."student`.`background`
WHERE `USERNAME` = '$studentUsername' AND `PASSWORD` =  MD5('$studentPassword') AND `STATUS` = '1'
LIMIT 1")
or die(mysqli_error($con));

// If User Exist
if(mysqli_num_rows($QUERYSTUDENT) > 0){
    $_SESSION["STUDENT"]    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QUERYSTUDENT)["USERNAME"];
}
```

}

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Live Server here: https://sts-dgpp.com
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the output of `mysqli_fetch_assoc($QUERYSTUDENT)["USERNAME"]`?  See if it contains anything.

Comment: What is the point of `mysqli` when you still insert parameters directly in your query?

Comment: @Blinkydamo Yes it contains exact user input. you can try: username: limsocheat, Password: 123456 https://sts-dgpp.com

Comment: @S.I. mysqli i used simple `mysqli` to connect to database only.

Comment: When I use this username and password and then I refresh the page sessions is still there for me. One silly question: You have session_start(); at the top of each page, right?

Comment: @S.I. Thanks testing, after ** Force Refresh ** the page, still you see the `array of SESSION` in the top header? for me see `array(0) { }`. Thanks

Comment: @S.I. Yes I include `session_start()` every page, for testing I don't header to any page, just stay in the same page after login, but SESSION is lost after I **Force Refresh**

Comment: Even with Force Refresh I still see `array(1) { ["STUDENT"]=> string(10) "limsocheat" }` at the top. However I don't know if I should get something but when I click some button all load with `404`

Comment: @S.I. Thanks for reply, I found the problem already because of `php.ini`. my `session_save_path` is not writeable because of `php.ini` after I **remove** session works. Thanks

Comment: Glad you found the problem and solution. You can post the solution as an answer to your question. It can be in help of others

Comment: And btw if this piece of source go live please update the query because is vulnerable to sql injections.

Comment: @S.I. Thanks for advice, actually i am also looking for the tutorials or php security, you can share me if you know some Advanced Security Tutorials, Thanks

Comment: It is very simple to prepare your statement. You can check here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp `// prepare and bind`. And here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem already because of `php.ini`. my `session_save_path` is not writeable because of `php.ini` after I **remove** session works. Thanks

Hope it help someone.

Comment: what exactly did you remove ?

Comment: @Sylvesterhillary, I removed the php.ini file, because I downloaded from another server.

Comment: Ok i see but why did you download php.ini from another server? Was it cus of the issue?

Comment: @Sylvesterhillary, yes I did, I downloaded from cloud IDE that auto generated the php.ini file.